# Allow text entry field for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This is my code HTML to generate the field destinate to datePicker:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-font input-size"> Date:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="date-picker-2" type="text" class="date-picker form-control input-borders" name="pdf_date"/>
            <label for="date-picker-2" class="input-borders input-group-addon btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my JS code to display the datePicker.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
    format: "dd MM yyyy"
});
```

I'm looking for a way to enter the text field will display the selected date, some text in particular.

But the text entry always disappears when you select a date.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I can generate an event by clicking on the field that displays the datepicker and add to html using the append attribute, a text?

I know it can be a bit basic question but I could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
  Shown Field : <input id="thedate" type="text" placeholder="dd MM yyyy" /><br />
  <input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      altField: '#thealtdate'
    });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```